# django-filter showing model objects when querying foreign key items

Tags: django, filter, foreign-keys, inner-join, django-filter

I have created a **filter** using **django-filter** that is supposed to **query** the **YearLevel** **field** and display row/s that matches the selected checkbox/es (Year 8, Year 9, Year ...).

Although, the filter slightly works, as it displays a functioning CharFilter/Field, which I can manually type in a year level and it returns the corresponding row/s; below it contains a bunch of checkboxes with primary keys as labels and returns nothing when selected.

[image: Filter Form with Checkboxes and CharFilter]

My models:

```py
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    RelatedPersonName = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    RelatedPersonFirstName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    RelatedPersonFamName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    StudentLegalName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    StudentFamName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=130)
    Street1  = models.TextField(max_length=30)
    Suburb = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    PostCode = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    StudentLegalName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    StudentFamName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    StudentNo = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=10)
    Class = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    YearLevel = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    objects = StudentProfileManager()
    
class AttendanceQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def get_yearlevel(self, yearlevel):
        return self.select_related('BCEID').filter(BCEID_id__YearLevel = yearlevel)

    def get_all_studentprofile(self):
        return self.select_related('BCEID')

class AttendanceManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return AttendanceQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def get_yearlevel(self, yearlevel):
        return self.get_queryset().get_yearlevel(yearlevel)

    def get_all_studentprofile(self):
        return self.get_queryset().get_all_studentprofile()

class Attendance(models.Model):
    BCEID = models.OneToOneField(StudentProfile,primary_key=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    AttendanceRate = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    objects = AttendanceManager()
```

Filters.py

```py
class YearLevelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    yearlevel = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Attendance.objects.all().distinct(),
        field_name="StudentNo",
        to_field_name="BCEID",
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        label="Year Level",
        label_suffix="",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ['BCEID__YearLevel']
```

Please help.

NB. Please ignore the camelcased vars.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by doing this:

```
class YearLevelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
   
    YEARLEVELS = (
        ('Year 7', 'Year 7'),
        ('Year 8', 'Year 8'),
        ('Year 9', 'Year 9'),
        ('Year 10', 'Year 10'),
        ('Year 11', 'Year 11'),
        ('Year 12', 'Year 12'),
    )

    BCEID__YearLevel = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=YEARLEVELS, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ['BCEID__YearLevel']
```